# Generic repository issue with inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, repository-pattern, petapoco

I have N-Layer solution in .Net with PetaPoco as microORM. I get the entities generated from the template generator of PetaPoco. These entities `T` derive from the base class `Record<T>`. Then I extend them adding more data access facilities and custom `Save()` and `Delete()` methods that override the `Record<T>` default methods.

Following is the overrided `Delete` method from the entity (the method I want to call)

```
public partial class Document : Record<Document>
{
    public new int Delete()
    {
        int rowsAffected;
        using (var uow = DB.GetInstance().GetTransaction())
        {
            rowsAffected = base.Delete();
            LogSystem("Deleting", "Deleting a document", 0, 0, GUID);
            uow.Complete();
        }
        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Then when I create the generic repository the methods getting called are from the base class `Record<T>` and not my custom ones from the entities. When I call an `entityRepository.Delete()` method, the `Delete()` method from my entity should get called and not the one from the default `Record<T>` class.

The generic repository class is as follwos:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : Record<T>, new()
{
    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        entity.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that in your `GenericRepository` you specify T as "something deriving from Record". So wenn calling `entity.Delete()`, this call will be linked to this base method, since this is only done once for all possible instances of T.

If you have access to the `Record<T>` class, just make the `Delete()` method virtual and override it in `Document`.

If not, try using something like this:

```
public class ExtendedRecord<T>: Record<T>
{
  public virtual new int Delete()
  {
    base.Delete();
  }
}

public partial class Document : ExtendedRecord<Document>
{
  public override int Delete()
  {
    // ...
  }
}

public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
  where T : ExtendedRecord<T>, new()
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This is "Solution 3:" as I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Finally I decided to not override the methods from the Record<T> class. Instead I move the Logging logic to the repository instead. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

> Confession: I have no knowledge of PetaPoco and its template generator.

The problem is more related to OO (specifically Inheritance) than PetaPoco IMHO. If generic repository is created with `Record<T>` which is also a base class for each entity, then what happening is as expected. You need to closely look into inheritance of your classes.

You may need to make few changes in the solution I am proposing below to match up with ORM functionality.

## Solution 1:

Declare a new base class or interface something like below:

```
public interface IEntityBase{.....
```

Include the necessary members like `Delete` method in interface.

Then, derive each entity from this interface as well:

```
public partial class Document : Record<Document>, IEntityBase
```

Then, create a generic repository with this interface instead of `Record<T>` **something** like below:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : IEntityBase
```

This way, you achieve your objective without changing much of your existing code.

## Solution 2:

Another **dirty** solution is to cast the `Record<T>` to its actual instance.

```
public void Delete(T entity)
{
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Document))
        Document myEntity = (Document)entity;
    myEntity.Delete();
}
```

Casting in each method is definitely bad idea. Look for some better centralized location in your code. I just wanted to show you the way.

## Solution 3:

Other thought is to make `Delete` method in `Record<T>` a `virtual` method. But I am not sure how your ORM works or even if your ORM allows this, so I will not comment on this.